# Proof of $L^1$ convergence of $f(\delta x)$ to $f(x)$

Tags: measure-theory

I wish to prove the following identity: Suppose $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then I want to show
$$
\lim_{\delta \to 1} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(\delta x)-f(x)| \ dx = 0 
$$
I have the following proposed solution - Since $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1$, I may pick $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|f-g\|_{L^1} < \varepsilon/3$. It follows that $\|f(\delta x)-g(\delta x)\|_{L^1} < \varepsilon/3$. Now,
$$
\|f(\delta x) - f\|_{L^1} \leq \|f(\delta x) - g(\delta x)\|_{L^1} + \|g(\delta x) - g\|_{L^1} + \|g - f\|_{L^1} \leq 2\varepsilon/3 + \|g(\delta x) - g\|_{L^1}
$$
Lastly, to estimate the remaining term, since $|g(\delta x) - g(x)| \leq |g(\delta x)| + |g(x)|$, the dominated convergence theorem applies, and by the continuity of $g$ we may conclude $\|g(\delta x) - g\|_{L^1} < \varepsilon /3$. This concludes the proof.

I would like the ask if there are any incorrect claims in my proof.

Comment: I think the inequality $\|f(\delta x)-g(\delta x)\|_{L^1}<\varepsilon/3$ need not be true, because you have to do a change of variables $u=\delta x$. You'll get $\|f(\delta x)-g(\delta x)\|_{L^1}<\varepsilon/3\delta$. This ends up being okay in the end when you take $\delta\to 1$ anyway.

At the end, you say $\|g(\delta x)-g\|_{L^1}<\varepsilon/3$. But the dominated convergence theorem does not say anything about a fixed $\delta$. It tells you about the limit. DCT will give you $\lim_{\delta\to 1}\|g(\delta x)-g\|_{L^1}=0$, which is what you want anyway.